# pthreads thread local storage with vs2017

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to port some legacy code to vs2017. the code uses pthreads.
I'm having trouble with the thread local storage declaration __thread.
This simple example when compiled with the 64 bit command line compiler cl.exe

```
#include <pthread.h>

__thread double * myptr;

void silly(void)
{
  myptr=(double*)0x12436;
}
```

produces the error message

> test1.cpp(3): error C2144: syntax error: 'double' should be preceded
>   by ';' test1.cpp(3): error C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

So __thread does not seem to be recognized. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Visual Studio uses `__declspec( thread ) int tls_i = 1; ` for example.  I think `__thread` is a g++/clang extension.  Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yh4a9k1.aspx  Also C++11 has `thread_local` see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: Thanks. that seems to have done the job.